# Continuation of functions beyond natural boundaries

Tags: analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation, pade-approximation, lacunary-series

The article [*Continuation of functions beyond natural boundaries*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44237555) by John L. Gammel states

> I am particularly interested in the convergence of the $[N/N+1]$ Padé approximants beyond the natural boundary, since, as is well known, Borel [2] has shown that there exists a kind of analytic continuation which differs from the usual kind (the theory of the usual kind is due to Weierstrass), and Borel made use of examples such as the ones studied here in showing that in some cases it is possible to continue functions beyond what Weierstrass called natural boundaries. I am interested in these examples because they seem to me suggestive of the direction in which comprehensive theorems about the domains in which Padé approximants converge and theorems about to what they converge are to be sought.

where [2] references

> E. Borel, *Lecons sur les fonctions monogènes d'une variable complexe*, Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1917.

Unfortunately, it is in French and inaccessible to me. Does anyone know what technique of Borel Gammel is referring to? How is it possible to continue a function beyond its natural boundary?

Comment: For a non-paywall version of the Gammel article: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250130961

Comment: The monograph of Borel is also [available at the internet archive](https://archive.org/details/leonssurlesfon00boreuoft/page/n8/mode/2up), and even if you anger not familiar with the Frech language, it is worth having a look at it.

Comment: [Generalised continuation by means of right limits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1175.pdf) also looks related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two phenomena where a given holomorphic function can be continued in some sense beyond its natural boundary, namely *overconvergence* and *generalized analytic continuation*: Gammel most likely refers to the last one, i.e. to generalized analytic continuation, which was precisely studied by Borel and his followers. A modern and very readable reference is [1], and particularly relevant to our question is chapter 3, pp. 21-35. And quoting verbatim the Authors of [1], (p. xi of the preface)

> "*Generalized analytic continuation (...) studies ways in which the component functions $f|_{\Omega_j}$ - where $f$ is a meromorphic function on disconnected open set $\Omega$ in the complex plane $\Bbb C$ and $\{\Omega_j\}$ are the connected components of $\Omega$ - may possibly be related to each other in certain cases where the Weierstrassian notion of analytic continuation says there is a 'natural boundary'.*"

The 'way' this happens is that an appropriate rational approximation (i.e. one satisfying appropriate conditions) to a part $f|_{\Omega_j}$ of a function $f$ characterized as above, *determines also other parts*.

**An example (the Poincaré example)** ([1] chapter 3, p. 11)

A typical holomorphic function which exibit this "superconvergence" behavior is
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{z-e^{i\theta_n}}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where

- $\{c_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an absolutely summable sequence of complex numbers $\big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_n|<\infty\big)$.
- $\{\theta_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers which is dense on the boundary of the unit disk $\partial \Bbb D$

It can be proved that, for $f|_{\Bbb D}$ and $f|_{\Bbb{C\setminus D}}$, the boundary $\partial \Bbb D$ is a natural boundary, thus standard analytic continuation cannot happen across any of its arcs, yet there exists a rational approximation \eqref{1} (as we can see, *de facto* the whole $f$ is defined by a series of rational functions, thus any finite truncation of it will do the job) such that, while univocally determining one of its parts, it does simultaneously the same for the other.

**Notes**

- According to [1] (pp. xii-xiii of the preface), generalized analytic continuation is a field of research which is wide open, and there are also several types of analytic continuation depending on the conditions assumed on the approximation used to define it.
- A similar phenomenon is *overconvergence*: it was discovered by Milton Brocket Porter and further studied by Jentzsch and Ostrowski.

**Reference**

[1] Ross, William T.; Shapiro, Harold S., *Generalized analytic continuation*, University Lecture Series. 25. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiii, 149 p. (2002), ISBN: 0-8218-3175-5, [MR1895624](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1895624), [ZBL1009.30002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1009.30002).

Comment: Can this be used to [extend the prime zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353047/regularizing-the-sum-of-all-primes) beyond its natural boundary?

Comment: I’m referring to the [prime zeta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) $P(s) = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} p^{-s}$, which can be analytically continued beyond $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$ (where the series converges) to $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 0$, but has a seemingly impenetrable natural boundary at $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 0$.

Comment: @user76284 I apologize for not having read carefully your comment, and remove my former comments. Regarding to the problem of generalized analytic continuation of the prime zeta function beyond the natural boundary $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$ almost all the methods described in [1] deal with singularities belonging to a compact set in the plane, therefore are not suited, without a further work of research, to construct such a continuation. However, there is a brief description of the work of Arne Beurling where the singularities can be dense in the plane and this could be a nice starting point.

Comment: @user76284 I'll add something more on this problem to the answer.

Comment: Can't we just apply the [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) mapping the imaginary line to the unit circle?

Comment: @user76284 you can try to avoid the problem of compactness of the singular set by using the methods of Beurling or a conformal mapping. However you have to be sure  that the axis $\{\operatorname{Re}(s)=0\}$ is the only natural boundary across to which you have to continue $P(s)$. Otherwise, even if you succeed in finding a rational approximation which leads to a generalized analytic continuation of $P(s)$, you may find out that the whole singular set is $\{\operatorname{Re}(s)<0\wedge\{\operatorname{Im}(s)=0\}\cup\{\operatorname{Re}(s)=0\}$

Comment: @user76284 and if you find out that the whole singular set is $\{\operatorname{Re}(s)<0\wedge\{\operatorname{Im}(s)=0\}\cup\{\operatorname{Re}(s)=0\}$ then you can do nothing since the sought for value $P(-1)$ lies inside the singular set. And generalized analytic continuation, like standard analytic continuation, does not assign to the analytic object it constructs a value on points belonging to its singular set.