# Continuation beyond the natural boundary with $f_+(z)=\lim_{x \to 1-} f(z,x)=\lim_{x \to 1-}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n^2}}{n^n}n^{-n^2 (1-x)} x^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, summability-theory, lacunary-series

Consider $z$ is complex and

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n^2}}{n^n}$$

This function has a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$.

Now I was thinking about summability methods or continuations beyond the natural boundary.

Define
$$f(z,x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n^2}}{n^n} n^{-n^2 (1-x)}x^n$$

Notice $f(z,1) = f(z)$.

Now let $f_+(z)$ be the proposed continuation of $f(z)$ that converges within some annulus $1 < |z| < r$.

Can we say

$$f_+(z) = \lim_{x \to 1-} f(z,x) = \lim_{x \to 1-} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n^2}}{n^n}n^{-n^2 (1-x)} x^n $$

If so, what is the value of $r$ ?

And if not, why not ?

How do we even do such limits ?

***edit***

Some are confused and think this is about analytic continuation, but that is not the case !

Analytic continuation through a natural boundary does not exist.

But it might be definable on the other side of the boundary.

Such as for instance

$$t(z) = \sum \frac{z^n}{(z^n - 1) n^3}$$

Is defined within and outside of the unit circle and it has a taylor series that only works within the unit circle.

See also :
[generalized analytic continuation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22generalized+analytic+continuation%22) and [*Continuation of functions beyond natural boundaries*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455514/continuation-of-functions-beyond-natural-boundaries).

And this paper :

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1175.pdf

Comment: It's a natural boundary. The singularities on the boundary are too dense to try to analytically extend through it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen the boundary is a natural boundary but it is bounded and $C^{\infty}$. The continuation is not analytic continuation. That would ofcourse be inpossible. Not every continuation is analytic continuation. We might have an analytic function beyond the boundary. Such functions exist.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen quote : The theory of generalized analytic continuation studies continuations of meromorphic functions in situations where traditional theory says there is a natural boundary.

Comment: See my edit too

Comment: I changed the question.